# RE2 regex engine, equivalent of (?<!re) expresssion

Tags: regex, re2

As per RE2 regex engine doc [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), `(?<!re)` is NOT supported.

What will be the equivalent of same if I want to achieve some thing like this e.g. how can I rewrite the below regex to work with RE2?

```
(?<!\\)%\{(.*?)\}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negation with character class:

```
[^\\]%\{(.*?)\}
```

`[^\\]` matches any character except `\`.